# Eevee. Grass in the distance looks white-grey

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I use a handpainted-grass for a Scene. In the Near, the colour is right, but in the distance the colour becomes white-grey.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Eevee?  Read the transparency section on this link: https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering

Comment: Thank You, for your answer! I Have this Problem in Eevee and in Cycles. I look at the linkt tomorrow once.

Comment: Oh! I have checked it again now: I have the problem only in EEvee, in cycles it looks like it should!

Answer (score 1):

It is a limitation on the way eevee deals with transparency.

As explained here: [Cycles vs Eevee 15 limitations](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering)

[image]

> Eevee’s Alpha Clip  layers materials from the front to the back, and looks nice and crisp. The trade-off here is that the material is either fully opaque or transparent, and can’t handle any blend between the two. **They also tend to get more transparent as you move away from them**. You can see in the example above that the tree in the back has its branches clearly showing through the leaves, even though it should be almost completely occluded